# ClearCase, use clearfsimport to perform brute force update

Tags: parent-child, clearcase

I've messed up my views a bit (big surprise for CC) and I have a child stream that has most of what I need, but not all. My parent stream needs to be updated, but I can't because of some issues (maybe evil twins I dunno).

Is it possible/wise to do the following
1) clear all elements in the parent stream
2) use clearfsimport to perform mass update on child stream
3) deliver child stream to parent

This is of course dependent on the fact that child stream elements are not deleted when deleted from parent.

Should I just clear out all elements of both views and start over? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do a clearfsimport from whatever source you want to the child stream.
But I wouldn't recommend "clearing" (as in "rmnam'ing") all elements from the parent stream, even though it doesn't `rmname` them in the child stream, as [my answer to your previous question details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8717359/does-rmname-on-parent-stream-remove-element-from-child-stream).

If you have a valid source (ie some directory with every file you need), you can clearfsimport it to your child stream view, in order to be complete.

Then try the deliver and identify the potential [evil twins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2927206/cleartool-question/2927385#2927385): your deliver will stop quickly at the "directory merge" stage, asking you to choose between two (identically named) files: you will chose the one coming from the child stream.
All the other files present in both stream will see their history updated as expected by that deliver.

Comment: Okay, It may not be evil twins. I'm getting the error "element not visible" when trying to merge. I did delete these "not-visible" elements in the parent stream before trying to merge. They were also removed in the child stream. I'm guessing changing a parent stream outside of a merge with identical updates of the merge is a no-no.

Comment: @Ian "element not visible" is usually not an error during a deliver, only a warning. Concentrate on the elements displayed with a white cross on a red circle: right-click on them and select "display element merge". Copy the error message in this comment, and I will troubleshoot/debug the issue.

Comment: Thanks Von. Thats okay I thought those "element not visible" warnings were stopping me from finishing the delivery, but after I resumed the delivery I discovered that 1 element had still not been merged. After merging it, it let me complete!