# How do delete a file in ClearCase UCM?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

I'm trying to delete a single version-controlled file in ClearCase. I already know that I'm supposed to check out the parent directory and its checked out.
I don't know if I'm supposed to check out the file I going to delete.

If I don't check out the file I get the error:

```
cleartool: Error: Not a vob object: "MyFileName".
```

If I do check out the file I get:

```
cleartool: Error: Element "MyFileName" has checkouts.
```

So ClearCase knows it's one of its files – but it doesn't want to delete it. I'm just baffled.
I've already updated and rebased repeatedly.

How do I move forward here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you see that error message "`has checkouts`", you need to do the command in a shell:

```
cd /path/to/view/your/view/path/to/parent/folder
cleartool rmname -force yourfile
cleartool checkin -nc .
```

See more at:

- "[Delete file from ClearCase checked out on another branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5215940/6309)", and
- The IBM technote "[About `cleartool rmname` and checkouts](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21232758)".

---

The [OP Tony Eastwood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/820757/tony-eastwood) reports in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20048285/how-do-delete-a-file-in-clearcase-ucm/20048582?noredirect=1#comment29893429_20048582):

> The issue seems to have been caused by me:
>
> - checking out the parent directory,
> - unchecking the parent,
> - **and then checking out the parent directory again**.
>
> **Surprisingly, once you've done this you have to run an update** (even though you have made no changes).
>   Once I'd run update it was happy to execute the `rmname` command.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  The issue seems to have been caused by me checking out the parent directory, unchecking the parent, and then checking out the parent directory again.  Surprisingly,  once you've done this you have to run an update (even though you have made no changes).  Once I'd run update it was happy to execute the rmname command

Comment: @TonyEastwood Excellent. I have included your conclusion in the answer for more visibility.