# is it possible to recover a deleted ucm view if uuid of the view is known?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

I try to deliver but it failed because the rebase is on process in another view.
This view has been deleted so how to I recover the view and cancel the rebase operation by setting in this deleted view and proceed further.

```
cleartool: Error: Checkouts disallowed in view
: a rebase is active using view "52df8e4.77de11e3.97f8.00:01:80:93:35:66" on this stream.
cleartool: Error: Unable to check out "".
cleartool: Error: Unable to checkout the directory element 
 This may cause additional checkout and merge failures for files and directories contained within
cleartool: Error: Checkouts disallowed in view
: a rebase is active using view "52df8e4.77de11e3.97f8.00:01:80:93:35:66" on this stream.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply reset that deliver to another view:
See "[Reset Deliver to Another View](https://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.ccrc.help.doc/topics/u_deliver_reset.htm)", and [`cleartool deliver`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_deliver.htm):

```
cleartool deliver -resume -reset -to aNewView -stream aStream@\apvob -gmerge
```

You might see:

```
cleartool: Error: The integration view cannot be retargeted because view "xxxx" has checkouts.
cleartool: Error: Unable to resume deliver.
```

In which case, it is best to cancel (unless you were in the "complete" step)

```
cleartool deliver -cancel -stream stream:Stream@\apvob -reset -to aNewView
```

You can also cancel all checkouts for the old deleted view with a (in a dynamic view)

```
cd /path/to/aVob
cleartool rmview -force -uuid uuid_of_the_deleted_view
```

See more at "[ClearCase: How to Uncheckout Files in Shapshot View Deleted From File System](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20101992/6309)".